# "Close" button on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any possibility to make a link  or a button to close the current page? Like I have this:

```
<div id="arrows">
        <a href="It works"><div id="arrow_left"></div></a>
        <a href="It works too"><div id="arrow_right"></div></a>
        <a href="??? =("><div id="arrow_close"></div></a>   
</div>
```

And this if it's necessary this:

```
#arrow_close{
height: 7px;display: inline;float: left;width: 7px;
background: url(../i/close-20.png) no-repeat;
}
```

And I want to close the page with a button "close".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`window.close()` or `self.close()` to close the present window.

To prevent the browser from prompting the warning, you need to set the `opener` property and then call the close.

```
<a href="JavaScript:CloseWindow();"><div id="arrow_close"></div></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CloseWindow = function() {
  window.top.opener = null;
  window.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, i think it will works. But i'm nooby in js.

So it will be like:
    <script src="final_files/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    
    ?window.opener = "something";
    MyNewDIvWithBUtton.onClick="javascript:window.close();"
    
    });
    </script>

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. But it doesnt works in Mozilla =\
Is it possible to make it work in Mozilla?

Comment: what all browsers did u try? and what is it doing for mozilla?

Comment: try changing window.opener = "something" to window.top.opener = null, updated the post, let me know if this worked

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">
```

(some browsers won't allow this if the window wasn't opened by a script, depending on the security features enabled)

Comment: @TRAVA: live with it, or forget it.

Comment: @Mef: that prompting can be bypassed

Answer (score 2):

You can do this inline pretty easily... on a div, you would do

```
onClick="javascript:window.close();"
```

But on an <a> tag, you can also do

```
href="javascript:window.close();"
```

Comment: How should i use it?
onClick="javascript:window.close();"

Comment: Using the setup you provided, you can do this one of 3 ways...

One.
<a href="javascript:window.close();"><div id="arrow_close"></div><a>   

Two.
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:window.close();"><div id="arrow_close"></div></a>   

Three.
<a href="#"><div onClick="javascript:window.close();" id="arrow_close"></div></a>  

It all depends on if you want the event to be triggered on the anchor or the div.

Comment: @TRAVA If you check the javascript console you'll probably see something like "Warning: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script." -- that's the security thing I was talking about in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660418/close-button-on-the-page/2660420#2660420)

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page looking for an answer to the question while implementing in-person signing using v6.0.0-rc of the DocuSign.ESign.dll. The error was:

UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope"

The answer I found was simple: The signer.Name and signer.Email have to be the same as the view options when you pass control to apiClient.envelopeApi.CreateRecipientView()

Here is the inPersonSigner partial code

```
   InPersonSigner signer = new InPersonSigner();

    signer.SignerName = signerName;
    signer.HostName = recipientName;
```

And here is the code to pass control to the browser to begin a signing-session in the same browser.

```
    RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
    {
        ReturnUrl = "https://www.cnn.com", // your URL here
        ClientUserId = "1234",  
        AuthenticationMethod = "email",
        UserName = signerName,
        Email = signerEmail

    };

    ViewUrl viewUrl = apiClient.envelopeApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeSummary.Data.EnvelopeId, viewOptions);
```

I have no idea if this is enough information to answer your question. I'm assuming that you are running a web page that is signing a document. But instead of sending an email via a DocuSign Signer object, you are doing in-person signing session (on the same browser) using the InPersonSigner object instead. If this isn't what you're doing, then my answer is inappropriate. But it worked for the situation I'm describing. And the question (above) is clearly dealing with DocuSign... possibly an older version.